# ReactiveCocoa subscribeCompleted in command never executes

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I am new to ReactiveCocoa and MVVM. I am trying to do simple login screen. 
My view controller in storyboard has 2 textfields (username, password) and one button. 
When the button is clicked it should send POST request username and password to server and receive secure token. When the response is received, it should execute sendCompleted. However subscribeCompleted in my RACCommand executionSignals block never gets executed and I can't go to next screen.

### ViewController.m

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
#import <ReactiveCocoa/RACEXTScope.h>
#import "ViewModel.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewModel *viewModel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (!self) return nil;

    _viewModel = [ViewModel new];

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Reactive stuff
    RAC(self.viewModel, username) = self.usernameTextField.rac_textSignal;
    RAC(self.viewModel, password) = self.passwordTextField.rac_textSignal;
    self.button.rac_command = self.viewModel.loginCommand;

    @weakify(self);
    // Logged in successfully
    [[[[self.viewModel.loginCommand.executionSignals logAll] flattenMap:^RACStream *(RACSignal *execution) { // I don't understand this part well. What does flattenMap do in this particular example?
        return [execution ignoreValues]; // I assume it should ignore sendNext:
    }] subscribeCompleted:^{
        NSLog(@"completed"); // This subscribeCompleted block never get called!

        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextScreen" sender:nil]; go to next screen or something similar
    }];


    // Error occured during login
    [self.viewModel.loginCommand.errors subscribeNext:^(id error) { // It works fine.
        NSLog(@"Login error: %@", error);
        // Show alert view
    }];
}

@end
```

### ViewModel.h

```
//  ViewModel.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class RACCommand;

@interface ViewModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) RACCommand *loginCommand;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *username;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *password;

@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isLoading) BOOL loading; // Used for loading indicatior view.

@end
```

### ViewModel.m

```
//  ViewModel.m


#import "ViewModel.h"
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
#import <ReactiveCocoa/RACEXTScope.h>

@interface ViewModel ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) RACCommand *loginCommand;
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isLoading) BOOL loading;

@end

@implementation ViewModel

// Initializer
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    _networkManager = [NetworkManager shared];

    return self;
}

// Getter
- (RACCommand*)loginCommand {
    if (_loginCommand) {
        _loginCommand = [[RACCommand alloc]initWithEnabled:[self validateLoginInputs] signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
            return [self loginUserSignal];
        }];
    }
    return _loginCommand;
}

// Methods
- (RACSignal*)validateLoginInputs {
    return [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, username), RACObserve(self, password)]
                             reduce:^id(NSString *username, NSString *password) {
                                 return @(username.length > 0 && password.length > 0);
                             }];
}


- (RACSignal*)loginUserSignal {
    @weakify(self);
    return [[[[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        @strongify(self);
        self.loading = YES;
        [self.networkManager validateLoginWithUsername:self.username
                                              password:self.password
                                               success:^(NSDictionary *jsonResponse) {
                                                   [subscriber sendNext:jsonResponse];
                                                   [subscriber sendCompleted]; // it doesnt work
                                               } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                   [subscriber sendError:error]; // however it works
                                               }];
    }] doNext:^(id x) {;
        // Save secure token to memory

    }] finally:^{
        // When error occurs or complete, stop animation spinner.
        @strongify(self);
        self.loading = NO;
    }]
            replayLazily];


}
```

## Update

I did something like this:

```
[self.viewModel.loginCommand.executionSignals subscribeNext:^(id signal) {
       [signal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
           NSLog(@"Logged in successfully");
           // [self perfromSegueWithIdentifier:@"SetPin" sender:nil];
       }];
    }];
```

But I don't think it is a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

self.viewModel.loginCommand.executionSignals - do not send "completed"

ViewModel.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) RACSignal *completed;
```

ViewModel.m

```
self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        RACSubject *completed = [RACSubject subject];
        _completed = completed;

[[[self.loginCommand.executionSignals map:^id(RACSignal *value) {
            return [value doCompleted:^{
                [completed sendCompleted];
            }];
        }] switchToLatest]
        subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        }];

    return self;
}
```